# Where can I find all same version of Geotools packages in same place?

Tags: geotools

I'm trying to use some Geotools packages but it is a nightmare to configure repositories to find all versions in same place.

This is my dependencies and repositories:

```
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.geotools/gt-api -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
        <artifactId>gt-api</artifactId>
        <version>${geotools.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.geotools/gt-epsg-hsql -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
        <artifactId>gt-epsg-hsql</artifactId>
        <version>${geotools.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.geotools/gt-main -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
        <artifactId>gt-main</artifactId>
        <version>${geotools.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.geotools/gt-metadata -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
        <artifactId>gt-metadata</artifactId>
        <version>${geotools.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.geotools/gt-opengis -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
        <artifactId>gt-opengis</artifactId>
        <version>${geotools.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.geotools/gt-referencing -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
        <artifactId>gt-referencing</artifactId>
        <version>${geotools.version}</version>
    </dependency>




<repositories>
    
    <repository> 
        <id>geosolutions.repository</id> 
        <name>Geosolutions Repository</name> 
        <url>http://maven.geo-solutions.it/</url> 
    </repository>
        
    <repository>
        <id>osgeo</id>
        <name>Open Source Geospatial Foundation Repository</name>
        <url>https://repo.osgeo.org/repository/release</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>osgeo-snap</id>
        <name>Open Source Geospatial Foundation Repository Snapshot</name>
        <url>https://repo.osgeo.org/repository/snapshot</url>
    </repository>

    <repository>      
      <id>geotools</id>
      <name>Geotools repository</name>
      <url>https://repo.osgeo.org/repository/geotools-releases/</url>
    </repository>  
      
    <repository> <!--Add the snapshot repository here-->
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
        <id>opengeo</id>
        <name>OpenGeo Maven Repository</name>
        <url>http://repo.opengeo.org</url>
    </repository>
    
    <repository> 
        <id>repository.spring.release</id> 
        <name>Spring GA Repository</name> 
        <url>http://repo.spring.io/release</url> 
    </repository>   

    <repository>
        <id>central</id>
        <name>Central Repository</name>
        <url>https://repo1.maven.org/maven2</url>
        <layout>default</layout>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>

    <repository>
        <id>spring-snapshots</id>
        <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>

    <repository>
        <id>spring-milestones</id>
        <name>Spring Milestones</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
    </repository>

</repositories>
```

And this is the result:

[image]

Need the version 20.x or above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you check the [manual](https://docs.geotools.org/stable/userguide/build/maven/repositories.html)?

> You can browse them online at:
>
> ```
>     https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/ - maven central
>
>     https://repo.osgeo.org/repository/release/ - OSGeo project releases (including GeoTools)
>
>     https://repo.osgeo.org/repository/snapshot/ - OSGeo repository for daily snapshots (including GeoTools)
> ```
>
> The repositories above act as a cache, gathering up artifacts from a
> range of projects into a single searchable location for the maven
> build system.

Comment: Well... ```https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/``` doesn't have ```org.geotools.xxx``` but ```repo.osgeo.org``` seems to working well until now.